# How to configure multiple solidity compiler versions in foundry?

Tags: solidity, compilation, compiler, foundry

I have a foundry project with files that have multiple solidity versions(0.7.x and 0.8.x). hardhat can relatively easily be configured to compile all files in the project as follows:

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/multiple-solidity-versions

Does foundry have built-in support for multiple solidity compiler versions? I came across a [hacky way to do this](https://github.com/hbarcelos/forge-multi-version) which is non-ideal and I don't want to take this approach.

Comment: According to the documentation, foundry will find the list of required compilers for your project as long as you do not set the `sol_version` in your configuration file, see [here](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/config/solidity-compiler#auto_detect_solc)

Comment: @Jaime thanks, your answer is almost correct, but it's not the `sol_version` that should not be configured in the `foundry.toml`, but the `solc` variable that should be omitted(`sol_version` isn't even a valid config variable), also the `auto_detect_solc` should be set to true or not set at all since it defaults to true. I'd be fine with giving you the bounty, if you provide a proper answer, but it's not mine to give :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it doesn't seem like Foundry allows you to manually configure multiple `solc` versions however Foundry does automatically detect and configure the required compilers for your project, you'll need to make sure of the following:

- Do not explicitly configure a solidity compiler version i.e. do not set the `solc` variable in your `foundry.toml` config.
- Ensure that [auto_detect_solc](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/config/solidity-compiler#auto_detect_solc) is set to `true` or leave it unconfigured(since the default value is `true`).

Here's an example of what your `foundry.toml` might look like:

```
# foundry.toml

[profile.default]
auto_detect_solc = true
# Do not include the 'solc' variable
```

Credit to @jaime for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that `auto_detect_solc = true` doesn't work, just set the compiler version for accurate testing.

```
#foundry.toml
// Specify Version
solc_version = "0.8.22"
//auto_detect_solc = true
```