How to test contract with old solidity version in Foundry?
I need to test contract that uses version ^0.5.16 in Foundry. I get this error ->
ERROR
ERROR foundry_compilers::resolver: failed to resolve versions
Error: 
Found incompatible Solidity versions:
test\OldVersionContract.t.sol ^0.8.0 imports:
    lib/forge-std/src\Test.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    src\OldVersionContract.sol ^0.5.16
    lib/forge-std/src/console.sol >=0.4.22, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/console2.sol >=0.4.22, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/safeconsole.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdAssertions.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdChains.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdCheats.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdError.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdInvariant.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdJson.sol >=0.6.0, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdMath.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdStorage.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdStyle.sol >=0.4.22, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdToml.sol >=0.6.0, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdUtils.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Base.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/console.sol >=0.4.22, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdStorage.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/console2.sol >=0.4.22, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/interfaces/IMulticall3.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/mocks/MockERC20.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/mocks/MockERC721.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/StdStorage.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol >=0.6.2, <0.9.0
    lib/forge-std/src/interfaces/IERC20.sol >=0.6.2
    lib/forge-std/src/interfaces/IERC721.sol >=0.6.2
    lib/forge-std/src/interfaces/IERC165.sol >=0.6.2

CONTRACTS
src/OldVersionContract.sol
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract OldVersionContract {
// Code is not relevant
}

test/OldVersionContract.t.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {Test, console2} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {OldVersionContract} from "../src/OldVersionContract.sol";

contract OldVersionContractTests is Test {
    OldVersionContract public oldVersionContract;

    function setUp() public {
        // ! Both lines give the same error
        // oldVersionContract = new OldVersionContract(user);
        oldVersionContract = deployCode("OldVersionContract.sol");
    }
}



Found this, but it doesn't work for me, any ideas why? How to Resolve Compiler Version Conflicts in Foundry Test Contracts?
I didn't make any changes in foundry.toml and changing version of my OldVersionContract.sol is not an option. Any ideas how I can test it?

might help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153534/how-to-configure-multiple-solidity-compiler-versions-in-foundry

Hi @ZartajAsfer, auto_detect_solc is set to true by default. I also tried setting it manually to true , it didn't help.

@MilosDjurica, it's getting compiled successfully on my end though. Please run foundryup command, and then try compiling again.

@SYEDASADKAZMI I tried foundryup too, but I keep getting the same error. I am also using Windows 10, not sure how relevant that is though.

Okay, but in Windows, you must be running Foundry on WSL, right?

After foundryup, can you try forge clean and then run forge build?

@SYEDASADKAZMI it is not working, are you sure that you have exactly the same code as I do?

Yes @MilosDjurica, I was just compiling the exact code of your OldVersionContract.sol file.

I faced this issue a couple of hours ago.
Two things were helpful in resolving it:

Setting a default solc_version like this solc_version = "0.8.27"

Closing your VS Code and opening it back after some minutes.


Surprisingly,  2 fixed it for me. Hope that helps!
